# How can I get the inner list value of list of keyvaluepair of (string, list)?

Tags: c#, .net

I am now struggling to find a way to get inner list from complicated List of keyvalupair.

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>> conditions = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>>();
```

I want list from above list using given string value as a key.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What if there are multiple matches? What if there are none? This sounds as simple as `conditions.Where(pair => pair.Key == key).Select(pair => pair.Value)` which will give you a sequence of `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` values for matching pairs...

Comment: Why use a `List<KeyValuePair<...>>` when you are trying to access it like a `Dictionary`?

Comment: You could use `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>` and access it with `conditions[key]`

Comment: I have some duplicate keys. That's why I use this list of keyvalupair instaed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` method like this:

```
conditions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "key").Value;
```

Or you should probably use a `Dictionary` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Dictionary` and a `Dictionary` as your value as well.

```
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> conditions = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();
```

and access it with `conditions[key]`

For example:

```
//Initialize random, pointless dictionary for example
var conditions = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>
{
    {
        "firstDict", new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            {1, "blue"},
            {2, "red"}
        }
    },
    {
        "secondDict", new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            {1, "car"},
            {2, "truck"}
        }
    }
};

//Get dictionary with key value "firstDict"
var firstDict = conditions["firstDict"];
//Gets the value associated with key "1"
var color = firstDict[1];
```